# How do I prove $|\left \langle x,y \right \rangle|=\left \| x \right \|\cdot \left \| y \right \|\Leftrightarrow y=cx,c\in F$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Proving $\Leftarrow$ is easy enough, it's just a matter of plugging it right in. For $\Rightarrow$, I tried changing the right side to $\left (\left \langle x,x \right \rangle \cdot\left \langle y,y \right \rangle  \right )^{\frac{1}{2}}$, and then having $|\left \langle x,y \right \rangle|=\left \langle x,\left \langle y,y \right \rangle x \right \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}$, but that looks off to me, and I don't know where to proceed even if it's right.

Comment: Left-to-right is false when $x = 0$. Also what fields $F$ are you looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $z:=x-\frac{\left\langle y,\,x \right\rangle}{\left\langle x,\,x \right\rangle}y$. Rearrange $\left\langle z,\,z \right\rangle \geq 0$, with equality iff $z = 0$, to $\left|\left\langle x,\,y \right\rangle\right|^2 \leq \left\langle x,\,x \right\rangle \left\langle y,\,y \right\rangle$. This inherits the above equality condition, which implies $x,\,y$ are parallel (if we regard the zero vector as parallel to all vectors). Strictly speaking, we can violate $y = cx$ with $x=0\neq y$, in which case we have $x = cy$ instead with $c = 0$.

Comment: Is there a similar method to this for proving that ||x+y||=||x||+||y||?

Comment: @George Since all terms are non-negative, you simply need to compare the squares of each side of that inequality (which you mistyped as an equation). The triangle inequality then follows from the one we've been discussing, which is called the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. I'll leave determining the equality condition as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: the correct statement you should prove is $$|\left \langle x,y \right \rangle|=\left \| x \right \|\cdot \left \| y \right \|\Leftrightarrow x,y\text{ are not linearly independent}$$*
(there is a distinction of cases to be made for $x=0$, for instance)

---

A classic approach: Consider the polynomial (in $\lambda$)
$$
P(\lambda) = \lVert x+\lambda y\rVert^2 = \langle x+\lambda y, x+\lambda y\rangle
= \lVert x\rVert^2 + 2\lambda \langle x,y\rangle + \lambda^2 \lVert y\rVert^2.
$$
It is a non-negative quadratic polynomial, so its determinant $\Delta = 4\langle x,y\rangle^2 - 4\lVert x\rVert^2\lVert y\rVert^2$ keeps a constant (non-positive) sign. This gives you Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Now, if you have equality above, the polynomial has determinant equal to zero (not strictly negative), so it must have a root... consider this root: it is a value $\lambda^\ast$ such that $0=P(\lambda^\ast) = \lVert x+\lambda^\ast y\rVert^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\mathrm{span}\{x\}$ and $P$ the orthogonal projection onto $S$. Then $Py=cx$ for some $c\in F$.

Thus

$\begin{multline}\|Py\|^2=|\langle Py,Py\rangle|=|\langle Py,y\rangle|\\=|\langle cx,y\rangle|=|c\langle x,y\rangle|=|c|\|x\|\|y\|=\|cx\|\|y\|=\|Py\|\|y\|...(*)\end{multline}$

If $Py=0$, done. if $Py\neq 0$ , then by $(*)$ we have $\|Py\|=\|y\|$. Now, by Pythagoras

$$\|y-Py\|^2+\|Py\|^2=\|y\|^2=\|Py\|^2$$

Thus, $\|y-Py\|=0$, or $Py=y$. But $Py=cx$ and done.